# Get valid value from a cell and updating Column using pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this below dataframe. The actual data is huge and has lots of NaN.

```
        Date        ID      Code   Value   Value1  Value2     Value3
0 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  zzz=ID   AAC=10    NaN        NaN
1 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  zzz=ID   AAC=01    NaN        NaN
2 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN  VEC=1        NaN
3 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN  VEC=2    AAC= 1 A
4 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN  VEC=3    AAC= 1 A
```

This is the final expected data.

```
        Date        ID      Code    zzz       AAC    VEC       AAC.1
0 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2     ID        10    NaN        NaN
1 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2     ID        01    NaN        NaN
2 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN      1        NaN
3 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN      2        1 A
4 1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2    NaN       NaN      3        1 A
```

I need to actually update the Column name with the value from the cells.

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlPath, 0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlPath,
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyy',
                        datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')
df = df.fillna('')
for ColumnName, values in df.iteritems():
    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        if '=' in str(value):
            df.set_value(index, ColumnName, str(value).split('=')[1])
            NewColumnName = str(value).split('=')[0]
            df.rename(columns={ColumnName: NewColumnName}, inplace=True)

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

But since one column is getting repeated, this is getting errored.
So, I thought, I could loop though the df and get the first valid value in a given column and put it in a list.

```
AllColumns = list(df.columns.values)
NewColNameList = []
for ColumnName, values in df.iteritems():
    a = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        while a < len(values):
            if '=' in str(value):
                if value != '':
                    print(index, values)
                    NewColNameList.append(value)
                    break
                a += 1
print(NewColNameList)
```

But I'm not as strong in While loops as i thought i was. Any help to get the required df is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

**Data Set:**

```
In [314]: df
Out[314]:
         Date        ID      Code   Value  Value1 Value2    Value3
0  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  zzz=ID  AAC=10    NaN       NaN
1  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  zzz=ID  AAC=01    NaN       NaN
2  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2     NaN     NaN  VEC=1       NaN
3  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2     NaN     NaN  VEC=2  AAC= 1 A
4  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2     NaN     NaN  VEC=3  AAC= 1 A
```

**Solution:**

```
def get_col_name(col):
    if col.dtype != object:
        return col.name
    s = col.loc[col.str.contains(r'\w+\=').idxmax()]
    if s and '=' in s:
        return s.split('=')[0]
    return col.name

df = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: get_col_name(df[x]) if x.startswith('Value') else x)
        .replace(r'\w+\=', '', regex=True))
```

**Result:**

```
In [83]: %paste
df = (df.rename(columns=lambda x: get_col_name(df[x]) if x.startswith('Value') else x)
        .replace(r'\w+\=', '', regex=True))
## -- End pasted text --

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
         Date        ID      Code  zzz  AAC  VEC   AAC
0  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2   ID   10  NaN   NaN
1  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2   ID   01  NaN   NaN
2  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  NaN  NaN    1   NaN
3  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  NaN  NaN    2   1 A
4  1945-12-30  H0010603  ZZZ008-2  NaN  NaN    3   1 A
```

Comment: This solves only half of the problem. I also need to add the column name from the text that need to be removed from the remaining cells.. Is there any way to do that?